# Как отправить картинку пользователю с помощью бота в вк

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

Язык Python, библиотека vk_api.
Проверял множество способов которые нашел в интернете, но ничего не работает.
Мне нужно когда пользоветель отправляет боту команду `/tabl`, бот отсылал картинку.

Проблема в том, что я немогу отсылать картинку.
Помогите кто знает.

Comment: _"Проверял множество способов"_, - какие именно? Обычно используется класс [`VkUpload`](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upload.html#vk_api.upload.VkUpload) и его метод [`photo_messages`](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upload.html#vk_api.upload.VkUpload.photo_messages) после чего полученный `access_token` прикладывается `attachment`'ом типа `photo` к сообщению.

Comment: Если можеш пример использования напиши пожалуйста

Comment: У меня получилось получить access_key, а как его в отправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для загрузки фотографии на сервер ВК используется класс [`VkUpload`](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upload.html#vk_api.upload.VkUpload) и его метод [`photo_messages`](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upload.html#vk_api.upload.VkUpload.photo_messages).

Данный метод вернёт нам ответ, из которого нам необходимо извлечь `owner_id`, `id` и `access_key`. Данные значения нам нужны для формирования `attachment`'а к сообщению.

`attachment` имеет следующий вид: `f'{type}{owner_id}_{id}_{access_key}'`.
Иногда `access_key` можно опустить, но для отправки в сообщениях он нужен.

Формируем его с типом `photo` и значениями, полученными выше.
Чтобы приложить его к сообщению, используется поле с тем же названием — `attachment`.

***Пример:***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.upload import VkUpload
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id


TOKEN = '...'
PEER_ID = ...


def upload_photo(upload, photo):
    response = upload.photo_messages(photo)[0]

    owner_id = response['owner_id']
    photo_id = response['id']
    access_key = response['access_key']

    return owner_id, photo_id, access_key


def send_photo(vk, peer_id, owner_id, photo_id, access_key):
    attachment = f'photo{owner_id}_{photo_id}_{access_key}'
    vk.messages.send(
        random_id=get_random_id(),
        peer_id=peer_id,
        attachment=attachment
    )


def main():
    vk_session = VkApi(token=TOKEN)
    vk = vk_session.get_api()
    upload = VkUpload(vk)

    send_photo(vk, PEER_ID, *upload_photo(upload, 'photo.jpg'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Данный код отправит в беседу (или ЛС) c `peer_id` равным `PEER_ID` изображение `photo.jpg`

Не забудьте заменить в начале кода переменные `TOKEN` (`access_token`) и `PEER_ID` на соответствующие им свои значения.

**UPD:**

Для отправки фото по `URL` его все равно придётся загрузить (хотя бы в ОЗУ).
Для этого можно воспользоваться модулями `requests` и `io`.

***Пример:***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.upload import VkUpload
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
import requests
from io import BytesIO


TOKEN = '...'
PEER_ID = ...
URL = '...'


def upload_photo(upload, url):
    img = requests.get(url).content
    f = BytesIO(img)

    response = upload.photo_messages(f)[0]

    owner_id = response['owner_id']
    photo_id = response['id']
    access_key = response['access_key']

    return owner_id, photo_id, access_key


def send_photo(vk, peer_id, owner_id, photo_id, access_key):
    attachment = f'photo{owner_id}_{photo_id}_{access_key}'
    vk.messages.send(
        random_id=get_random_id(),
        peer_id=peer_id,
        attachment=attachment
    )


def main():
    vk_session = VkApi(token=TOKEN)
    vk = vk_session.get_api()
    upload = VkUpload(vk)

    send_photo(vk, PEER_ID, *upload_photo(upload, URL))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, завтро проверю

Comment: Все работает но, я хотел бы узнать как отправлять файл используя url? Просто когда я пытаюсь отправить по url, у меня появляется ошибка f = open(filename, 'rb')

Comment: @Antonio Что значит _"используя `URL`"_? Вы имеете в виду, что у Вас есть ссылка на фото, которое необходимо загрузить, и Вы не хотите его сохранять? Тогда можно загрузить его в ОЗУ, отправить на сервер ВК и очистить ОЗУ.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @Antonio Только что привёл пример, можете посмотреть :)

Comment: Благодарю, какраз отправился на поиски информации по работе с озу в python